# Particle remote control

Tags: particles

Is there any possibility to create remote control for particle number? I mean I have 62 particle emitters for many characters and is there any way to control all of them in one time, to create something that allows me to change particle amount in one place for all emitters.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, maybe. The script below will set the count of ALL the particle systems in the scene except those that have been manually edited. I looked for a way to set the value of only selected objects (bpy.context.selected_objects) but couldn't find a way to access the count from there.

```
import bpy
D = bpy.data

for particle in D.particles:
    particle.count = 1000
```